# markercluster issue on google maps

Tags: javascript, salesforce

When i am trying to display the Marker Cluster on Google Maps with the below code, it is throwing some errors. Please find below code and errors.
When i excecute the code outside salesforce it is working but inside Vf page ,it is not working . Can anyone help me?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},

        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]
    </script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8Bz5GIlx4K7sBv2ZLjr5HUtHhkTx2TMk&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
 </apex:page>
```

When i excecute the code outside salesforce it is working but inside Vf page it is not working . Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please proofread your questions before asking them

Comment: I have edited the question, please ignore for any mistakes. i am new to this Stackoverflow

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q+A forum designed to present it's questions and answers, so that _professionals and avid hobbyists_ have good reason to use the information we provide here. Questions that are not proper are discouraged.

Comment: "i" should be capitalized, "Please find code and errors" makes no sense. "c" in "can anyone help me?" should be capitalized, and you are missing commas in several places. Please correct these mistakes.

Comment: means , the above question is not clear? I have posted the issue which i am facing and the code which i  tried .

Comment: Edited the question as per your comments , please igone the these type of mistakes. I really struck on this need quck help:)

Comment: Think of it this way. University professors, Doctoral candidates, and Researchers and Developers from high-grossing companies like Google, Microsoft, Mozilla, etc use this website. Present your information properly, because you are presenting it to them.

Comment: And I am not here, because I was suggested to answer, but suggested to edit from SO's review queue.  That is why I am here.